# Swift ArcGIS basemap

Tags: ios, swift, arcgis

Create a new tiled layer with my custom URL

Set the new basemap as the basemap of the map

Run on the app can't display map, but in Xcode show:"Received data: 2607 bytes"

please help me Run on the app show the map, thanks

```
import UIKit
import ArcGIS

class ViewController: UIViewController, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDataDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: AGSMapView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Set up the map
        setupMap()
        
    }
    
    func setupMap() {
        // Create a new map with an empty basemap
        let map = AGSMap(basemap: AGSBasemap())

        // Create a new tiled layer with your custom URL
        let customVectorTiledLayer = AGSArcGISVectorTiledLayer(url: URL(string: "my-URL")!)

        // Create a new basemap with your custom tiled layer
        let customBasemap = AGSBasemap(baseLayer: customVectorTiledLayer)

        // Set the new basemap as the basemap of the map
        map.basemap = customBasemap

        // Set the new map as the map of the AGSMapView
        mapView.map = map

        // Create a new URLSession instance with self as delegate
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

        // Create a new data task with the customVectorTiledLayer's URL
        let task = session.dataTask(with: customVectorTiledLayer.url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                // Handle the error
                print("Error: \(error)")
                return
            }

            if let data = data {
                // Handle the received data
                print("Received data: \(data)")
            }
        }

        // Start the data task
        task.resume()
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
        // Handle the received data
        print("Received data: \(data)")
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            // Handle the error
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }

}
```